# result from get method is not displaying in View angular 2

Tags: angular, get, angular-ui-router, angular2-template, angular2-forms

am working on angular2, I  need to get all details from getmethod. (I got this)

now I need to display all this details in my form. Everything look fine, but it is not displaying.

**This is my html** (this is where my problem, the result not showing in the label)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="userdetails">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2> Profile </h2>
        </div>
                <div *ngIf="editProfile === 2">                           
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="editProfileDetail(1)"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i> Edit </button>
           </div>
            <div *ngIf="editProfile === 1">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="editProfileDetail(2)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i> Close </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   
<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="userdetails">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="text-input"> Username </label>
    <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf="userdetails">
        <label class="form-control ">{{(userdetails.username == "" ? "--No data--" : userdetails.username)}}</label>  
    </div>                 
</div>
```

**My Ts File**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit
{
    public userDetails : UserData;

    constructor( private fb: FormBuilder, public http: Http,private     dataService: DataService)
    {
    }

    ngOnInit(){        
       let usernme = localStorage.getItem('username');
       this.dataService.getUserdata(usernme).then(userdata => this.userdata = userdata);
    }
```

**Service File**

```
getUserdata(user): Promise <UserData>
{
    let params : URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('username',user);

    return this.http.get(AppConfiq.API_URL+'getUser',{ search: params})
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => response.json().abcd as UserData)
       .catch(this.handleError);       
}
```

**UserData File**

```
export class UserData{
username: string; }
```

and I did get all the result I want[image]

I have problem with displaying part. Any idea or did i miss something?

Thank u.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning anything to `userdetails`.

Your callback

```
.then(userdata => this.userdata = userdata);
```

does the assignment to `this.userdata`. I think it was meant to be

```
.then(userdata => this.userdetails = userdata);
```

and you can use the safe-navigation operator (`?`) inside your label like this to check for falsy values:

```
<label class="form-control ">{{(userdetails?.username}}</label>
```